# Movie Maker stops working after upgrading GPU

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, amd-radeon, windows-movie-maker

I have Windows Essentials 2012 on Windows 8.1 with an ATI Radeon 3100 Graphics Card. The Graphics card had some OpenGL issues so I had to upgrade it from "(Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1)" or something like that. When I upgraded the graphics card, Movie Maker stopped working. I have to uninstall the graphics card to use Movie Maker and re-install it to use other programs (Blender, Photoshop, etc.). I tried re-installing Windows Movie Maker but that didn't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: It is not clear what you have done.  WDDM 1.1 isn't even what Windows uses.  It sounds like you don't have current display drivers (for your card since its now unsupported) installed.

Comment: @Ramhound I do have the current display drivers but I have to keep uninstalling it and re-installing it.

Comment: You should be using WDDM 1.3 since you are running Windows 8.1 the fact you are NOT running WDDM 1.3 meas you are not installing device drivers that support Windows 8.1.  You need to clarify what you did exactly.

Comment: the 3100 is a legacy product, last drivers were Catalyst 13.1 [January 2013] Link here for Win8 32-bit - http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%208%20-%2032 As a general rule, don't get drivers from Windows Update, get them from the GPU maker.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's the one I have. I resorted to using Movie Maker 2.6.